# wrapping/using a ServicedComponent

Tags: c#, com

I've been given a lump of code that has a ServicedComponent in it. I'm wrapping it up so that I don't have to expose the client code to yet another assembly dependency. The problem I'm having is injecting the connection string so that the Construct override will use the correct db.

Any ideas?

Thanks In Advance,
Josh Robinson

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I had to use the registry to read the connection string from. I understand (but have not verified) that it *is* possible to get a per-component .config file - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/florinlazar/archive/2003/12/04/41369.aspx